# Jetpack compose Internal Padding

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, padding, uiswitch

Is there an easy way to remove the switch's internal padding in compose?

I tried supplying a 0.dp in its modifier but it doesn't get rid of the internal paddings

```
 Switch(
      modifier = Modifier
           .padding(0.dp)
           .background(Color.Red), // just to show the internal box paddding
      checked = true,
      onCheckedChange = { }
 )
```

[image: Switch]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Composables such as Switch, CheckBox, RadioButton, Button, Slider and others i can't recall at the moment have minimum 48.dp size because of [minimum touch target for accessibility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fO5GF.png).

You can remove it with `CompositionLocalProvider`

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalMinimumInteractiveComponentEnforcement provides false) {
    Switch(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(0.dp)
            .background(Color.Red), 
        checked = true,
        onCheckedChange = { }
    )
}
```